# Is there any way to print out an specific element from an array with just its index number?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Well, I want to print out the name of the month from the `.getMonth()` method.

Keeping in mind that the array index starts from 0, I've made this code:

```
let date = new Date();
let month = date.getMonth();
month -= 1;
// As array index start from 0 but month from 1, I'm subtracting 1 from it so it too will start from 0.
let months =
[
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec",
]
```

Now I want like if it's May, I will keep the value 4, then subtract 1, which is 3.
The 3rd index in the array months is "May", but how will I ask it to check for the element with its index number?

***NOTE*** :  Please don't suggest if statements, because I don't want to use if statements for just displaying elements.

Comment: getMonth  returns 0 for January ... subtracting 1 from 0 results in -1 ... don't subtract one

Comment: though ... `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short'}).format(date)` is even better than writing your own table :p

Comment: by the way `The 3rd index in the array months is "May"` ... no, it's `Mar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy: use the [bracket property accessor notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```js
let date = new Date
let month = date.getMonth()

let months =
[
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec",
]

console.log(months[month])
```

Arrays are little more than objects with properties named after the positive integers (ie. `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'` etc). Because JavaScript is weakly typed you can supply a number (eg. from `getMonth`!) to the bracket property accessor notation, and the value will be coerced to a string, giving you the result you want.

But, as Jaromanda X points out, the better way is to use the Intl API because this will guarantee accuracy for a given user locale:

```js
const date = new Date
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short'}).format(date))
```